How to let Chrome know that a user accepted third party cookies?
Today my little website doesn't load perfectly in Google Chrome. A JavaScript has been not loaded by Chrome.
Chrome says:

Chrome is moving towards a new experience that lets people make an
informed choice with respect to third-party cookies.


Because third parties cookies are blocked by Chrome. What are the parameters (cookies and values) Chrome is checking in my browser?

That new warning in Chrome does not have anything to do with why your website isn't loading. net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET means your connection was closed. Adblocking software of something similar could be the cause.
